# PCINT of PortC for an analog device

Tags: interrupt, analog

[image]I would like to use analog signals from joystick axes in program. Firstly, I found out that external interrupts can be applied for 2 and 3 pins of PortB only. Now I am trying to use PCINT for A0 and A1 pins for instant reaction in program and implementation transition between modes of alarm clock, which is the main goal of a project. I saw how it cold be done with encoder, but I have a joystick physically. Can PCINT-interrupts can be used to react changing of analog signals?
Target part of code and breadboard diagram are below.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <ezButton.h>

#define set0(R,b) R&= ~(1<<b)
#define set1(R,b) R|= 1<<b

//#include <avr/io.h>
//#include <avr/interrupt.h>

int lcd_V0 = 13;
int RS = 11;
int RW = 10;
int E = 9;
int D4 = 4;
int D5 = 5;
int D6 = 6;
int D7 = 7;

int DHT11 = 12;
int Buzzer = 8;
int Joystick_button = 1;

LiquidCrystal lcd(RS, RW, E, D4, D5, D6, D7);
RTC_DS1307 rtc;
ezButton button(Joystick_button);

int Joystick_X = A1;
int Joystick_Y = A0;
bool X_changed = false;
bool Y_changed = false;
volatile int X = 0;
volatile int Y = 0;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.display();

  rtc.begin();

  pinMode(Buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Joystick_button, INPUT_PULLUP);

  set0(DDRC, 0);
  set1(PORTC, 0);
  set0(DDRC, 1);
  set1(PORTC, 1);
  set1(PCICR,PCIE1);
  set1(PCMSK1,PCINT8);
  set1(PCMSK1,PCINT9);
}

void loop() {
  button.loop();
  if(X_changed){
     X = analogRead(Joystick_X);
     Y = analogRead(Joystick_Y);
     lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
     lcd.print(String(Y) + String(X));
     }
  if(Y_changed){
     X = analogRead(Joystick_X);
     Y = analogRead(Joystick_Y);
     lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
     lcd.print(String(Y) + String(X));
     }
  }

ISR( PCINT1_vect )
{
  if((PINC&(1<<0))==0){Y_changed = true;}
  if((PINC&(1<<1))==0){X_changed = true;}
}
```

Comment: `PCINTx_vect` are for GPIO pins. There is `ADC_vect` (ADC conversion complete vector). Open the datasheet and search for "Interrupt Vectors" table within the datasheet and read the chapter about ADC to see how to use it, or alternatively google "ATmega328 ADC interrupt".

Comment: If the joystick is going to be operated by a human, or any sort being incapable of sub-millisecond moves, then you don't need interrupts. As long as your `loop()` is non-blocking, simply reading the analog values within `loop()` will be fine.

Comment: There is no equivalent of Pin Change interrupts for the ADC. While you can trigger the ADC automatically and then interrupt on completion via ADC_vect, that is not fitting for your situation. Also you would need to switch between both A0 and A1, since there is only one ADC in the Uno. I second Edgar here: There is no good reason to use interrupts for this. Your current `loop()`  is already running faster than any human can notice or react, even if you don't check for a changed pin. So just do it in `loop()`